# How feature importance is calculated in regression trees?

Tags: regression, random-forest, decision-tree, feature-selection

In case of classification using decision tree algorithm or Random Forest we use gini impurity or information gain as a measure to decide which feature to select first for splitting parent/intermediate node but if we are conducting regression using decision tree or random forest then how is feature importance calculated or the features selected?

Answer (score 1):

For regression (feature selection), the goal of splitting is to get two childs with the lowest variance among target values.
You can check the 'criterion' parameter from [regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html) vs [classification](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html) from sklearn library to get a better idea.

You can also check this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nSaOuPCNvlk